# Is there any method of calling a subroutine or function within a newly opened frame? Java

Tags: java, swing, subroutine

I know how to call up one class from within another:

```
 new frame().setVisible(true);
```

But I don't know how you do this but call up a subroutine on that at the same time e.g

```
new frame().setVisible(true);
Sub123();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assign the result of the `new` command to a variable and interact with it

```
frame aframe = new frame();
aframe.setVisible(true);
aframe.Sub123();
```

You may also consider taking a look at [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html)

Answer (score 4):

You need to do less compression of your code. You're creating an object anomymously via:

```
new Frame().setVisible(true);
```

and so have no variable with which to call methods on your object.

so instead do:

```
MyFrame myFrame = new MyFrame();  // create a variable!
myFrame.setVisible(true);
myFrame.someMethod();    // use it!
```

As an aside, you will want to learn Java naming methods and abide by them, including starting class names with upper-case letters. Doing this will improve the readability of your code.